# Controller is not going into for loop :javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a piece of code in javascript like this,

```
                        alert(attributes.length);
                        for(temp=0;temp<attributes.lenth;temp++){
                            attribute_list+="<option value='"+attributes[temp]+"'>"+attributes[temp]+"</option>";
                            if(temp==0)
                                alert(attributes[temp]);
                        }
                        attribute_list+="</select>";
                        alert(attribute_list);
```

First alert showing a length of 58 (i.e, length of attributes array) but the control is not going into the for loop

Comment: attributes.lenth should be attributes.length, typo error?

Comment: Controller renders the javascript, it does not execute the javascript, so why should it go into for loop?? JS is executed on client browser.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you check the loop it self ?

```
alert(attributes.length);
for(temp=0;temp<attributes.lenth;temp++){

/* test the loop */
console.log(attributes.length);

}
```

if console log show as long as attributes length, its mean loop works well. So you have to check process inside loop.